# How to receive a intent from abd shell command line

Tags: android, android-intent

I am just a new starter studying Android; I am trying to use intent-filter to receive an ACTION_DIAL intent from the ADB shell; here is what my ADB command is: "am start -a android.intent.action.DIAL -d "tel:1234567"
I was planning to use my app to receive this intent after it is launched, and read the phone number from it; it received intent for the first time but could never receive them again, here's what I contained in my manifest file.
my app uses the target api 31.

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="tel"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

and in my main activity here is only those code:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.getData()!=null) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "TEST";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
```

I am not sure how the getIntent() works, it seems like a listener that can be triggered by multiple times, but the only intent I could receive is the "android.intent.action.MAIN", which is the default intent when the activity start

Comment: "and in my main activity here is only those code" -- what method does that code reside in?

Comment: I just used the default blank activity from the android studio, and I put those codes in the onCreate() function

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#ManifestForTasks), "If an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the current task, the system routes the intent to that instance through a call to its `onNewIntent()` method, rather than creating a new instance of the activity."

So, my guess is that your first activity instance was still running, and you did not override `onNewIntent()` to handle the second and subsequent `Intent` objects.